# Regarding URL rewrite

Tags: asp.net, webforms

for url rewite when my hyperlink point the url like www.mysite.com/content?ID=20 but i want to know how to write logic that url  www.mysite.com/content?ID=20 will become www.mysite.com/mycontent of hyperlink when user mouse over the link.

i have another quetsion that how to write logic very easyly that will redirect the request to www.mysite.com/content?ID=20 internally when the url is actually click www.mysite.com/mycontent.

please guide me in detail with sample code. i am working with asp.net webform version 3.5.

thanks

Comment: You would like to hide the query-string that you are passing right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not wrong check this post

[ASP.NET : Hide Querystring in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493456/asp-net-hide-querystring-in-url)

and also URL Rewriting

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx