# What page event does encrypt/decrypt of querystring belong in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, query-string

I want to use the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493456/asp-net-hide-querystring-in-url) post in a base page that every page on my website inherits from to automatically encrypt/decrypt the querystring.  What event/events should this code go in?

So instead of: http://localhost/bob.aspx?custid=444
Should get something like: http://localhost/bob.aspx?custid=A%3de89d8

**EDIT: Decided to use http module for this purpose**

Comment: That should be dictated by when / where you need to use it.

Comment: @Mr. - There are more places than I can count, it is cleaner the way I want to do it for several reasons that I don't need to explain.

Comment: Querystring will be encrypted?

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do? First thing is that query and copy are references to the same thing, so copy is not a copy and if you change copy you change query. Second You want to take the querystring values that come in from the browser, and then turn it into binary data and then back to text in a different encoding.  Then you want to "decode" it when it hits your page.  What on earth for?

Comment: @Ben - See my answer in my answer :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a httpmodule [here](http://madskristensen.net/post/HttpModule-for-query-string-encryption.aspx)

Comment: Already written, tested, works as expected.  No use reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

If you do it in the Init event, the values will be processed and ready for you to use in the Load event for all of your pages.  A very common use of the Init event is for adding dynamically created controls for a page, so the Init event seems like a very good place to also prepare your query string values.

I personally use the Init event for encrypting/decrypting query string values, too.

Comment: Finally, someone with an answer!  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: What do you mean by set it?  Do you mean take the key/value pairs and encrypt them?

Comment: Ya, thought I would have to read the querystring, encrypt the querystring, then response.redirect?

Comment: Can you describe the exact process of what is happening on your side?