# How to hide querystring value in url

Tags: asp.net, url, query-string

Requesting a page from GridView's RowCommand event, here is the code

```
    protected void grdClaimList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "ViewClaim":
            Response.Redirect("ClaimStatus.aspx?id=" + e.CommandArgument);
            break;
    }         
}
```

I would like hide the query string from url, is it possible? if yes, please let me know how?

Comment: It's not exactly the same but if applicable you may use a POST instead of GET request (data won't be in the URL).

Comment: Is **[Server.Transfer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx)** a good enough alternative?

Comment: [Data options in 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @Adriano in which form I need to give "GET" method, the gridview page or calling page?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hide the query string from url"? Do you mean you want the target page to have access to the id value but you don't want it to be visible in the query string?

Comment: @KodeKreachor your are correct

Comment: Delphian, there is an example in the link posted by @thantos

Comment: [ASP.NET : Hide Querystring in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493456/asp-net-hide-querystring-in-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use session variables or view states instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible but you could encrypt in and then decrypt it on the other side if you don't want the User seeing it and putting different values in.

Comment: Read the comments, it is very possible.

Comment: @thantos I think chead23 means that literally hiding a value in a query string but still accessing it using query string accessors isn't possible. Of course it's possible to get the value over to the target page by other means as noted in the comments, but none of them are hiding a value in a query string.

Comment: I think I answered the OP's question. They asked if it was possible to hide the Querystring in the URL.